# Making Bootstrap styles override native Rails styles

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, button

I want Bootstrap styling to always supersede Rails native styling.

The example that's driving this is the following code:

`link_to "Delete all CIDNE reports", :class => "btn btn-info"`

Does not style the link in the button fashion you would expect from Bootstrap. It remains looking like an ordinary generic blue link. How do I ensure Bootstrap styles take precedence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Styles are included in order which they're are listed in application.css(sass/scss etc) in your assets folder. By defaults the whole directory required using `require_tree .` Which means an alphabetical order. 
And rails only  provides you with styles when you do the scaffolding and it gives you scaffold.css. So if you're including file called bootstrap.css, it should go before that file.